# How to attach drop down selected field data with email using outlook 2013

Tags: email, outlook, vbo

I am working on Outlook 2013 to custom form. I want to send data with e-mail which i chosen from drop down. I have designed the form using developer tools in outlook but no idea how to set chosen field text with email.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate custom controls with user properties that may contain values between sessions. See [Customizing Outlook Message Forms](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=61) for more information.